# Rails: Undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `reminder` model set up with a "date" column to indicate the date of an event, a "repeating" column to indicate whether the event repeats, and a "mail_date" column to mark the date the reminder email should be sent out.  I have the following in my model:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :create_mail_date
  after_create :send_reminder_emails
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  private

  def create_mail_date
    @reminder.mail_date = @reminder.date - 7.days  <<< ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
  end

  def send_reminder_emails
    @reminder.each do |reminder|
        ReminderMailer.reminder_send(reminder.user, reminder).delay(run_at: reminder.mail_date)
        reminder.set_new_dates
    end
  end

  def set_new_dates
    case @reminder.repeating
    when "Weekly"
        @reminder.date = @reminder.date + 1.week
    when "Monthly"
        @reminder.date = @reminder.date + 1.month
    when "Yearly"
        @reminder.date = @reminder.date + 1.year
    end
    @reminder.create_mail_date
  end
end
```

I'm getting a `undefined method`date' for nil:NilClass`error when I try to edit a`reminder`, which is confirmed by the fact that at this point @reminder comes back as`nil`.  Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?  Am I supposed to put these methods in the controller?  The edit method in the controller is as follows, so`@reminder` technically should be defined:

```
def edit
  @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
  @reminder.save
  render layout: 'nofooter'
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: In the model, try self.date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @reminder would make sense if these methods were in a controller that was passed an instance of the Reminder class, represented by the @reminder variable.  Since you're performing all of the work within an instance of the Reminder class, all of those @reminders should be self.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.

Comment: since self is assumed here, you can leave that out, too.  Just use self.___ when you need to (during assignment primarily)

Answer (score 0):

@reminder is not instantiated in your model. It is an instance variable that you have created in your controller. As Bob suggested in comment, you can try self.date. However, since you are within the model itself, you should be able to do the following:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :create_mail_date
  after_create :send_reminder_emails
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  private

  def create_mail_date
    mail_date = date - 7.days
  end

  # this method doesn't make sense! Does a reminder have multiple reminders?
  # maybe you are looking for something like this:
  def send_reminder_emails
    Reminder.all.each do |reminder|
        ReminderMailer.reminder_send(reminder.user, reminder).delay(run_at: reminder.mail_date)
        reminder.set_new_dates
    end
  end

  def set_new_dates
    case repeating
    when "Weekly"
        date = date + 1.week
    when "Monthly"
        date = date + 1.month
    when "Yearly"
        date = date + 1.year
    end
    create_mail_date
  end
end
```

Comment: Good point about the `send_reminder_emails` method.  That makes zero sense.  I'll reconfigure.  Thanks.

Comment: Can't do this `mail_date = date - 7.days`, ruby will create a local variable.  `self.mail_date = date - 7.days` is needed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working on a Rails 4 project on Ubuntu 20.04.

I had two models in my project - **Project** and **DailyRecord**

I was trying to do this to see the data I will get:

```
<%= project.daily_records.where(date: project.daily_records.last.date.pluck(:price).sum %>
```

However, I was getting an error:

> undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that some projects did not have any data yet for `daily_records` in order words, no daily records have been created for the projects yet, which made it have not value for `date`, thus returning `nil`

All I had to do was to define it in a method in my **models** and then use an `if` conditional to check for when the data is `nil`:

```
def daily_records_date
  daily_records = DailyRecord.last.date
  if nil
    return Time.now
  else
    daily_records
  end
end
```

And then I called it in my views:

```
<%= project.daily_records.where(date: project.daily_records_date).pluck(:price).sum %>
```

I will still make some changes to dry the code a bit more, and more most of the db queries to the models.